# Windows Server: VPN clients cannot see LAN clients

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, rras, sstp

I'm trying to set up a server running Windows Server 2012 R2 to host VPN (RRAS). I have gotten VPN connections to work with certificates (SSTP). Now I need the VPN clients to be able to see LAN clients, and LAN clients to see VPN clients. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I've bought a 2nd NIC because I read somewhere that this was needed. All VPN clients get IPs in the range 192.168.2.2-192.168.2.10 while LAN clients get IPs like 192.168.1.x.

Illustration:

VPN Client <--Internet--> Personal Router <--LAN--> VPN Server

From the outside the VPN connections are port forward to the VPN Server. Connections are established and work fine. But a connected VPN Clients cannot connect to the LAN clients nor the internet when connected through VPN.

I haven't been able to figure this out. Does anyone have any tips or links to instructions on how to do this? I don't actually know what to search for in this instance.

Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating a static route in the router like this:
192.168.2.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2